# Playframework 1.2.4: get the results of render() as a String?

Tags: templates, playframework, playframework-1.x

In a play framework 1.2.4 Controller, is it possible to get the contents of a template or tag as a String before output to the browser?

I want to be able to do this:

```
String json = renderAsString("/path/to/template.json", var1, var2);

//then use json as the body of a Play.WS request body.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution is based on the assumption that you are talking about PlayFramework 1.x**

If you are using [Groovy template engine](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates):

```
Map<String, Object> args = ...
Template template = TemplateLoader.load("path/to/template.suffix");
String s = template.render(args);
```

And you have a shortcut way if you are using [Rythm template engine](http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm):

```
String s = Rythm.render("path/to/template.suffix", param1, param3...);
```

Or you can also use named arguments:

```
Map<String, Object> args = ...
String s = Rythm.render("path/to/template.suffix", args);
```

**Note** the Groovy way also works for Rythm if your template file is put under `app/rythm` folder.

Answer (score 0):

*In addition to [green answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406860/595223)*.

If creating a json is what you want you would better use gson rather than building your own string with groovy templates. Gson is included in Play Framework 1.2.X.

You can find more information [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). Example from Gson doc:

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
    private int value1 = 1;
    private String value2 = "abc";
    BagOfPrimitives() {
        // no-args constructor
    }
}


BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);  
//json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```

You can also use Flexjson instead of gson.

Comment: I was already using org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper for this. I just wanted a way that would show the JSON file format as a template instead of hidden behind the scenes. Not sure if one is better than the other, but there could be performance considerations (but I don't really care about that right now).

Comment: if you use groovy for template, then it might be slower than gson or jackson, if you use rythm or japid, the template approach performance is better than gson/jackson as they are all static compiled java class by nature